# Retrieve info from link on page being scraped

Tags: python, scrapy, hdf5

I am building a scraper using scrapy on python 3.5.

I am scraping projects in a crowd funding forum and saving the data in a hdf5 file.

Scraping the projects is done by reading in a list of urls, which is scraped and the information of each project is then saved as a tabel row (with multiple columns). This is the top of my script:

```
class ExperimentScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'project_scraper'
    allowed_domains = ['projectname.com']

    dt = pd.read_csv("urls.csv") #list of urls
    start_urls = dt["url"].tolist()

    def parse(self, response):

        title = response.css('h1.title::text').extract_first() #name of project
        tags = response.css('a.tag.category::text').extract() #project tags

        ...
```

Unfortunately some of the project information is placed in an sub-link (e.g. .../methods). I would like to get the information from this link into the same row of the hdf5-file as the other information from the project. How can this be done?

Could I build a parser inside the parser I am already using?

Answer (score 1):

One way is using [requests chaining](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) method. Here you collect data from subsequent pages and pass interim data in `Request`s `meta` attribute until you finally yield a complete item.

Another way is using [`scrapy-inline-requests`](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests) library. Here you can incorporate interim data extraction into your main parsing method.